# Set Location of Button on a Window

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, layout-manager

As practice, I've been trying to make a simple tic tac toe game to see how layouts work in java. Now that I have the base code, with all of the rules and variable checks, I cannot find out how to get the buttons to line up the way I want. I wanted to make a 3x3 grid of buttons, but whenever I try a tutorial online or find someone with a similar problem, it always leads to the buttons not showing up at all. The following code gets the buttons on the screen, but doesn't arrange them.

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    //JPanel
    JPanel pnlMainBoard = new JPanel();

    //Buttons   
    JButton btnTest = new JButton("Test");
    JButton btnAI = new JButton("A1");
    JButton btnBI = new JButton("B1");
    JButton btnCI = new JButton("C1");
    JButton btnAII = new JButton("A2");
    JButton btnBII = new JButton("B2");
    JButton btnCII = new JButton("C2");
    JButton btnAIII = new JButton("A3");
    JButton btnBIII = new JButton("B3");
    JButton btnCIII = new JButton("C3");

    public Main(){
        //Layout
        //pnlMainBoard.setLayout(null);
        //Game set bounds
        btnTest.setBounds(60,400,220,30);       

        //JPanel bounds
        pnlMainBoard.setBounds(800,800,200,100);        

        //Add buttons to frame
        pnlMainBoard.add(btnTest);      
        pnlMainBoard.add(btnAI);        
        pnlMainBoard.add(btnBI);        
        pnlMainBoard.add(btnCI);        
        pnlMainBoard.add(btnAII);       
        pnlMainBoard.add(btnBII);       
        pnlMainBoard.add(btnCII);       
        pnlMainBoard.add(btnAIII);      
        pnlMainBoard.add(btnBIII);      
        pnlMainBoard.add(btnCIII);      
        add(pnlMainBoard);      

        //JFrame Properties
        setSize(400,400);
        setTitle("Ultimate Tic Tac Toe");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);   
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

}
```

So far this is the only code I've created that successfully puts the buttons on the screen, and when I change it the buttons disappear. How do I make it so I can set the location of the buttons where I want them on the window?

Comment: And ..where does that code attempt to use a `GridLayout`?

Comment: BTW - Consider putting the grid of buttons into a `JButton[][] buttonGrid = new JButton[3][3];`

Answer (score 2):

For a 3x3 grid check out the swing grid layout that you can set the JPanel to use like this:

```
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3,3);
JPanel.setLayout(grid);
```

Where jpanel is the name of your jpanel in your program...

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ThreeByThreeWithButtonLayout {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    ThreeByThreeWithButtonLayout() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        int gap = 10;
        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        JButton testButton = new JButton("Test");
        JPanel buttonConstrain = new JPanel(
                new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, gap, gap));
        buttonConstrain.add(testButton);
        ui.add(buttonConstrain, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3, 5, 5));
        gridPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap));
        ui.add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        String[] buttonRows = {"A", "B", "C"};
        for (int ii = 1; ii < 4; ii++) {
            for (String buttonRow : buttonRows) {
                JButton b = new JButton(buttonRow + ii);
                b.setFont(b.getFont().deriveFont(32f));
                gridPanel.add(b);
            }
        }
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                ThreeByThreeWithButtonLayout o = new ThreeByThreeWithButtonLayout();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("3x3 + Button");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GridLayout makes some rows and columns to your frame/panel like this :

```
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3,3);
Jpanel.setLayout(grid);
```